# DropDownListFor throwing ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Not sure what's going on here...

My controller methods looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RequestAppointment()
{
    var appointmentRequest = new AppointmentRequest
    {
        Stylists = _repository.Stylists // <-- Debugging shows that Stylists IS being populated here
    };

    return View(appointmentRequest);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestAppointment(AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Process...
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }
    return View(appointmentRequest);
}
```

The form looks like this:

```
@model MyDomain.Models.AppointmentRequest

@using(Html.BeginForm("RequestAppointment", "Appointment" FormMethod.Post))
{
    // This following line throws the exception:
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Stylist,
        Model.Stylists.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name })))

    <input type="submit" value="Make Request" />
}
```

The drop down list is populated form with the correct text & values. But when the form is submitted, the exception is thrown. What's going on?

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector) +6396316
   ASP._Page_Views_Appointment_RequestAppointment_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projects\OasisSalon\OasisSalon.Mvc\Views\Appointment\RequestAppointment.cshtml:9
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +825460
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825488
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Read the stack trace.  You haven't shown us any code that runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: @SLasks, there's the stack trace

Comment: Exception definitely looks like `Stylist` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the `Stylists` property in your POST action if you intend to redisplay the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestAppointment(AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Process...
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }

    appointmentRequest.Stylists = _repository.Stylists;
    return View(appointmentRequest);
}
```

You get a NRE because you are attempting to render a DropDownList in your view using `Model.Stylists` in your view but obviously this property is null after the POST action is executed as you never assigned it and its value is not populated automatically because all that's sent into the POST request is the selected value of the dropdown list (the `Stylist` property).

Comment: Even though the other answers echoed the same idea, this answer most clearly illustrates the correct solution. Thanks yet again Darin! You are the MVC wizard!

Answer (score 3):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're returning `View()` from the POST action without creating a model.

Comment: @Slasks, I've added more of the POST method's implementation so you can better see what's going on

Comment: @ErOx: My psychic powers were mostly correct.  The model-bound model from the POST doesn't have `Stylists`.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC does not have ViewState. So it can not keep the Values of DropDown list across postbacks like ASP.ENT Webforms does. So I guess, in HttpPost Action method, you are returning the `appointmentRequest` to the View but the Stylists Property is null. You probably needs to reload it before returning the `appointmentRequest` back to the view.

Comment: I've never had to do that before... When the model is given to the POST version, all the values are kept in place, no?

Comment: @ErOx: Available options in dropdown element won't be available in your post action method. You will get values of selected item, TextBox values etx sice The HTML helper creates a hidden variable to hold those.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what is happening here is that `Stylists` is null in your Post action.  It is not being bound during model binding, as the drop down list is for `Stylist`, not `Stylists`.

You would need to rebuild the `Stylists` property before passing the `appointmentRequest` model to the view.